# XML Invalid DTD error

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

.

**Validate Online:** http://xmlvalidator.new-studio.org

[**XML Document**](http://pastebin.com/UkEt0mT3) *(also displayed below)*

### Question 1

When I uncomment the following line no. 4

```
<!ELEMENT persona (#PCDATA|(name,dob?,address*)) >
```

AND comment the following line no. 5

```
<!ELEMENT persona (name,dob?,address*) >
```

Why the following error shows?

- Line 4 Column 28 : An element type is required in the declaration of element type "persona".

*Here, I want that user can EITHER use parsable character string OR can write the name, dob & address tags and write the info in them.*

### Question 2

When I replace the encoding from "ISO-8859-1" to "utf-8", and load the page in browser (Google Chrome); it shows the following error.

```
error on line 2 at column 21: Encoding error
```

*But validation is successful & OK.*

**Why does it show that error?**
Which encoding is good?

### The XML Document with embedded DTD

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE personality [
<!ELEMENT personality (persona*) >
<!-- <!ELEMENT persona (#PCDATA|(name,dob?,address*)) > -->
<!ELEMENT persona (name,dob?,address*) >
<!-- <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA|(first_name,last_name)) > -->
<!ELEMENT name (first_name,last_name) >
<!ELEMENT first_name (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT last_name (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT dob (date+,month+,year+) >
<!ELEMENT date (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT month (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT address (building,street,city,state,country,country_code) >
<!ELEMENT building (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT street (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT state (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT country (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT country_code (#PCDATA) >

<!ATTLIST persona id ID #REQUIRED >
<!ATTLIST name type (string|number) "string" >
<!ATTLIST dob type (string|number) "number" >
<!ATTLIST address type (string|number) "string" >

<!ENTITY author "Miguel Pitts" >
<!ENTITY website "example.com" >
<!ENTITY email "miguelpitts4MN@teleosaurs.xyz" >
<!ENTITY copyright "Copyright © Miguel Pitts" >

]>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="xmlstyle.css" ?>

<personality>
    <persona id="p1">
        <name type="string">
            <first_name>Miguel</first_name>
            <last_name>Pitts</last_name>
        </name>
        <dob type="number">
            <date>12</date>
            <month>02</month>
            <year>1989</year>
        </dob>
        <address type="string">
            <building>1233</building>
            <street>15</street>
            <city>NY</city>
            <state>Bangkok</state>
            <country>China</country>
            <country_code>82</country_code>
        </address>
    </persona>
</personality>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here, I want that user can EITHER use parsable character string OR can write the name, dob & address tags and write the info in them.*

Understandable, but not allowed by the XML spec (for the reasons outlined by Nic Gibson in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433285/dtd-and-mixed-content/4436609#4436609)).  Your best bet is to redesign your XML slightly; you might, for example, declare

```
<!ELEMENT persona (str | (name,dob?,address*) ) >
<!ELEMENT str (#PCDATA) >
```

or you could declare

```
<!ELEMENT persona_simple (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT persona_struct (name,dob?,address*) >
```

*Why does it show that error? Which encoding is good?*

Are those trick questions?  It shows that error because it detects that the character encoding of the input cannot possibly be the character encoding declared.  By "which encoding is good?" I assume you mean "which encoding should I name in my document's encoding declaration?" -- the answer to that question is "the encoding that you use in the document".  If you're asking the question, I guess you aren't sure which encoding your document actually uses; judging from the behavior you describe, it looks as if the document is in fact not using UTF-8 but ISO 8859 part 1.

Comment: @c-m-sperberg-mcqueen what behavious does a UTF-8 encoding requires that is not provided by ISO-8859-1 or vice versa? I'm don't happen to know much about encoding.

Comment: `<!ELEMENT persona_simple (#PCDATA) >

<!ELEMENT persona_struct (name,dob?,address*) >`

is not what I intended. 

But 

`<!ELEMENT persona (str | (name,dob?,address*) ) >

<!ELEMENT str (#PCDATA) >` 

works great! Thanks.

Comment: @absk007, good question.  A short answer: ISO 8859 defines fixed-width character sets; any 8-bit value represents a character. UTF-8 is a variable-width encoding; values x80-FF occur only in the context of multi-byte sequences, and the first value of such a sequence must be in the range xC0-FD.  The copyright character in your document is xA9 in ISO 8859, xC2 xA9 in UTF-8. The sequence x20 xA9 x20 cannot appear in a UTF-8 data stream.  See a good introduction to UTF-8 (for example [this one](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8)) for more.

Answer (score 0):

change your persona ELEMENT as shown below

```
<!ELEMENT persona (#PCDATA | name | dob | address)* >
```

[for your reference](http://www.featureblend.com/dtd-elements-mixed-content.html)

Comment: I don't want that.

Here, I want that user can EITHER use parsable character string OR can write the name, dob & address tags and write the info in them.

Comment: Why there is a * in the end of

    <!ELEMENT persona (#PCDATA | name | dob | address)* >

Comment: @mzjn plz post your above comment as an answer so that I can mark it as the best answer.

Comment: @absk007: I would prefer not to duplicate an existing answer. Once you are allowed to vote up answers (you need 15 rep points), I think you should vote up http://stackoverflow.com/a/4436609/407651.